# Can't install AEM developer tool plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aem

I tried to install the AEM developer tool plug in in eclipse by downloading the com.adobe.granite.ide.p2update-1.0.4.zip at local and installing. But it failed with the following message:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     `Software being installed: AEM Developer Tools 1.0.4 (com.adobe.granite.ide.feature.feature.group 1.0.4)
>     Missing requirement: Sling IDE Tools, M2e-based 1.0.6 (org.apache.sling.ide.m2e-feature.feature.group 1.0.6) requires 'org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: AEM Developer Tools 1.0.4 (com.adobe.granite.ide.feature.feature.group 1.0.4)
>       To: org.apache.sling.ide.m2e-feature.feature.group 1.0.6

So what is missed in my eclipse(Luna version), I think maybe I need to installed another plugin or something else that can provide "org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group",I googled the "org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group" but haven't get the exactly info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by setting network proxy in eclipse. Set your network proxy in eclipse-->preferences-->general-->network connections, then re-install the plug-in, tata~~~ problem resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this `"org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group"` bundle on eclipse website and put into the plug-in folder, then run as administrator for eclipse, it should work.

in my case, it shows require `org.eclipse.equinox.ds`, so I just get what it needs. it could work for a similar situation.